# Select different values from table based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

The table structure is as below:

```
++ID++++READ_ID++++READ_TYPE
  101    201          30
  102    201          35
  103    201          40
  104    201          60
  105    202          50
  106    202          60
```

I need to select the READ_TYPE based on the following condition:

Condition 1: Check for each READ_ID if either 30,35 or 40 is present. If present select the maximum READ_TYPE present among 30, 35 and 40.
For instance READ_ID 201 has 30,35,40 and 60. The result must be 40.

Condition 2: If 30, 35 or 40 is not present fetch the maximum of the read_type.
For instance READ_ID 202 has 50 and 60. The result must be 60.

How can this be achieved from a single oracle SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select read_id,
       (case when sum(case when read_type in (30, 35, 40) then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when read_type in (30, 35, 40) then read_type end) 
             else max(read_type)
        end) as themax
from t
group by read_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `KEEP` clause to get what you want:

```
select read_id
     , max(read_type) keep (dense_rank last
                              order by case when read_type not in (30,35,40)
                                            then 1
                                            else 2
                                       end
                                     , read_type) max_read_type
  from Your_Table
  group by read_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query. I tested it on an example and it works fine on oracle.

```
select READ_ID, MAX(READ_TYPE) from tab
where READ_TYPE in (30,35,40)
group by READ_ID
union
select READ_ID, MAX(READ_TYPE) from tab t1
where not exists 
(select 1 from tab t2 where t2.READ_TYPE in (30,35,40) and t1.READ_ID = t2.READ_ID)
group by READ_ID
```